# Is JPA bad choice to deal with EAV Data models?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to use JPA/Hibernate to CRUD operate an EAV data model and have been facing lot of performance hit. I am looking for ideas to efficiently manage EAV data models.

```
**(A)**So here is an example of what I am trying to deal with, I have three tables :
UserTable
AttributesTable
UserAttributeValueTable

**(B)**And apart from these three, I have other relations like :
ItemTable
UserItemsRelationTable
```

So basically, AttributesTable is a table that contains all the attributes, may it be User's or Item's. And UserAttributeValueTable is the table that joins UserId, AttributeId, and a value.

Now, let's say I want to pull all the users and their attributes.

Here is how I mapped them :

```
@Entity
UserTable{     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private long userId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=UserAttributeValueTable.class, mappedBy="userTable", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserAttributeValueTable> userAttributeValues;

    //Other Columns        
}

@Entity
UserAttributeValueTable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="USER_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID")
    private long userAttributeValueId;     

    @Column(name="\"VALUE\"")
    private String value;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AttributesTable 
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=AttributesTable .class ,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    private AttributesTable attributes;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserTable 
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=UserTable.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private UserTable user;

    //Other columns

}


@Entity
AttributeTable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    private long attrId;

    @Column(name="ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
    private String attrName;

    //Other columns
}
```

Problems :
1. I ran into an infinite loop when I did a findAll , and that was obvious, so I used @JsonIgnore so that it would ignore the UsersTable. However, to retrieve 300 User's(User Attribute Values), it is taking a lot of time and I am not looking for every column either. All I want is to flatten it this way:

```
User :[{ id:"1", name:"John", otherAttributes={attr1:"value1",attr2:"value2"},{ id:"2", name:"Joey", otherAttributes={attr1:"value1",attr2:"value2"}]
```

2. Mapping complexity, when mapping with other kind of relations like **(B)**

I just felt after writing simple SQL queries would be more easier in these kind of dynamic models where the column is a not a field instead it is a property. Any suggestions ?

I am using Spring Data JPA.

Comment: I recently worked on an app with data in a similar structure. The approach taken was  to create DB views over the top of the flattened DB data. These views gave us a more relational view of the data and only included the fields we were interested in. The JPA entities were mapped to these views.  In our case, this data was read-only: not sure if the approach would work if this wasn't the case.

Comment: What is the performance of the raw SQL generated from the JPA query?  With EAV models, the SQL performance is usually an issue.  If you do need to stick to EAV, first tune the raw SQL by reducing and ordering joins and introducing indexes.  If even that doesn't get the performance within your desired limits, you will need to explore a flat table structure, like Magento [does](http://inchoo.net/magento/flat-tables-in-magento-and-product-collection/).  This will certainly not be easy with JPA.

Comment: @AlanHay See that's the catch, we need to insert as well, its not just read-only. I thought about the views option, but backed out when inserts came into picture. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: @manish We do need to stick to EAV. The problem is JPA is not running single query with inner joins, it is running multiple queries to retrieve each attribute's value. Only if it is based of a primary key, it is running the inner joins query. Writing an sql query was more easier than getting them to work with JPA. We are still researching into it. Im not sure how Magento does it, but thanks for the inputs, I will try tuning the query with the indexes.

Comment: You can always use raw SQL with JPA.  Just generate the SQL in your code and run it via the JPA provider.  That is, if you are sure that your raw SQL is performant.  The general rule with any ORM is that in the odd case you cannot achieve the right level of performance with a query, switch to plain JDBC and raw SQL.